# Image change & content collapse onclick in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have been trying to achieve functionality of collapse-expand and image toggle at the same time using jquery.

Ans all is working just fine except:

when i click on any heading all other contents collapse but only image of same heading is toggling.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".content").hide();
jQuery(".heading").click(function() {
    jQuery(this)
        .nextAll(".content:first").slideToggle(500)
        .siblings(".content").slideUp(500);

    var currentimg=$(this).find('img').attr('src');
    if(currentimg=="images/right.png"){
        $(this).find('img').attr('src','images/Down.png');
    }
    else{
        $(this).find('img').attr('src','images/right.png');
    }

});
```

});

My jsfiddle is :https://jsfiddle.net/pa1b5g0j/
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you nee https://jsfiddle.net/nzsexknm/

Comment: Hi appreciate the such  a quick reply

Comment: but this script is toggling all images . May be question was confusing. What  i want is : when i click on any heading its image should change to down.png and rest all MUST have right.png.....

Comment: jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pa1b5g0j/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the other images src with `Down` image. See inline comments

```
//Find current elements image
var img = $(this).find('img');
img.attr('src', function(_, value) {
  if (value == "http://diactral.com/v2/images/right.png") {
    return 'http://diactral.com/v2/images/Down.png';
  } else {
    return 'http://diactral.com/v2/images/right.png';
  }
});

//Set the image apart for all image apart from elements image
jQuery(".heading img").not(img).attr('src', 'http://diactral.com/v2/images/Down.png');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/22avq3rz/2/)